# First time PC Desktop build for budding designer/developer

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, memory, development

I'm looking to self-build a PC that will last at least 4-5 years without needing upgrading. I will be looking to dual-boot Windows and Linux, run Adobe CS programs from Photoshop through to After Effects/Premiere, and want something that will be capable of smoothly running 3D modeling software in the future (or at least be possible to expand to be capable of this in the future).

I'm new to the world of hardware, so may be way off the mark - please be kind.

Is it worth getting an Intel Core i7 or should I opt for an i5 for now? Do I need a Hex core or can I stick to a quad? I've seen getting a SSD is worth it. Any recommendations?

Is 8GB memory enough or should I plump for 16GB?

How high spec a graphics card do I need? Is this up to the job: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Gigabyte-Nvidia-Graphics-Card-PCI-E/dp/B00NM3BWVS ?

Do I need a GPU?

Thanks for any advice you can give!

Comment: As someone who's built a few boxen I'd keep upgrading in mind for the future. While I'm a somewhat experienced system builder, I'd suggest starting with a budget and building around it. Off hand, most hex cores are either AMD (which I'd rather avoid personally, intel has better chips at the moment) or EE ones. Start with a budget and one of the builds here http://www.logicalincrements.com/ then adjust stuff in pc parts picker. Some minmaxing may be needed. This would probably something better for chat, IMO but of course, you need the 20 rep. Also, might be worth splitting the question up.

Comment: Also, passively cooled card. I'm not fond of those outside specific purposes. I consider a *60 series my personal minimum but I'm a gamer. As for ram, 8gb is probably enough, but 16gb would be nice in some circumstances - least in the vfx industry, some tools were super ram hungry.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold for now because you're asking so many questions in one post that it'll be very difficult to effectively answer all of them. Have a read of [these guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality). Generally, you should ask about one component per post. I recommend starting by choosing a motherboard.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will split it up! Thanks for the responses so far.

Comment: Just to add, if you get 20 rep *or* I can work out how to invite you to chat, I'd be pretty happy to walk you through the process of working out what you need, and a few useful resources.